# Images imported into Mac PowerPoint 2011 have a low resolution

Tags: images, resolution, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

Running Lion and Office:Mac 2011. Searched everywhere. No matter what I do images (pictures) that I import into slides immediately go to a very low resolution and quality.

How do I prevent this drop is resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off picture compression. In Microsoft PowerPoint 2013, this [can be done as follows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/powerpoint-help/turn-off-picture-compression-HA010355184.aspx):

1. Click the File tab.
2. Under Help, click Options, and then click Advanced.
3. Next to Image Size and Quality, click the file that you want to turn off picture compression for.
4. Under Image Size and Quality, select the Do not compress images in file check box.

[image]

Note that it only applies to the pictures you import after having changed the setting. The already imported images will keep their low resolution, so you need to reimport them again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but try this:

Right click image in Mac Office 2011 Powerpoint > Format Picture...

In the left menu click Size

On the right side you can either try checking the box "Best scale for slideshow" and then changing the resolution to what you'll be using (defaults to computer resolution)

Now you can also check the ribbon. Click Themes and on the left click Slide Size and go to Page setup.

Hope this helps!